# Get text indent of HTML select elements

Tags: javascript, html-select, text-indent

At HTML Select elements there is around `4px` indent.

How can I calculate/ get the exact value using JavaScript

I tried this but doesn't get me the correct value

```js
const el = document.querySelector('select');
const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(el);
computedStyle.textIndent // '0px'
computedStyle.padding // '0px'
```

[image: select-indent]

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. If you do not need this information dynamically, try just using photoshop or another image editor to count the pixels manually. P.s. what do you need this information for? Maybe we can help with the wider question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to determine based on [CSS box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). In your case I would expect it to have a `pading-left`. You want the space from the select border to the text content. This is affected by the select padding, the option margin, the option border and the option padding.

```js
select = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('select'))
option = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('option'))
console.log(select['padding-left'])
console.log(option['margin-left'])
console.log(option['border-left'])
console.log(option['padding-left'])
```

```html
<select><option>Item</option><select>
```

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(select.querySelector("option")).paddingLeft` is prefect

Answer (score 0):

You on the right track

```
const el = document.querySelector('select');
const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(el);
var indent = computedStyle.textIndent ;
var padding = computedStyle.padding ;
var margin = document.getElementById("myDiv").style.margin;
```

Just assign them to variables also using query selector you could have more than one on the page so it would hide the specific one your looking for hence why I prefer to call things through and ID